# Getting FactoryBot object attributes for API requests with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I am setting up RSpec request tests, and I have the following test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "ClientApi::V1::ClientContexts", type: :request do
  describe "POST /client_api/v1/client_contexts" do
    let(:client_context) { build :client_context }
    it "creates a new context" do
      post "/client_api/v1/client_contexts", params: {
        browser_type: client_context.browser_type,
        browser_version: client_context.browser_version,
        operating_system: client_context.operating_system,
        operating_system_version: client_context.operating_system_version
      }
      expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
      expect(json.keys).to contain_exactly("browser_type", "browser_version", "operating_system", "operating_system_version")
      # and so on ...
    end
  end
end
```

The corresponding factory is this:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :client_context do
    browser_type { "Browser type" }
    browser_version { "10.12.14-blah" }
    operating_system { "Operating system" }
    operating_system_version { "14.16.18-random" }
  end
end
```

Now, obviously, that all seems a bit redundant. I have now three places in which I specify the attributes to be sent. If I ever want to add an attribute, I have to do it in all of these places. What I actually want to do is send the particular attributes that the Factory specifies via POST, and then check that they get returned as well.

Is there any way for me to access the attributes (and only these!) that I defined in the Factory, and re-use them throughout the spec?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I should prefix this with a warning that abstracting away the actual parameters from the request being made could be seen as detrimental to the overall test expressiveness. After all, now you'd have to look into the Factory to see which parameters are sent to the server.

You can simply get the Factory-defined attributes [with `attributes_for`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#using-factories):

```
attributes_for :client_context
```

---

If you need more flexibility, you *can* implement a [custom strategy](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#custom-strategies) that returns an attribute Hash from your Factory without creating the object, just building it.

Create a file `spec/support/attribute_hash_strategy.rb`:

```
class AttributeHashStrategy
  def initialize
    @strategy = FactoryBot.strategy_by_name(:build).new
  end

  delegate :association, to: :@strategy

  def result(evaluation)
    evaluation.hash
  end
end
```

Here, the important part is `evaluation.hash`, which returns the created object as a Ruby Hash.

Now, in your `rails_helper.rb`, at the top:

```
require 'support/attribute_hash_strategy'
```

And below, in the `config` block, specify:

```
# this should already be there:
config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods

# add this:
FactoryBot.register_strategy(:attribute_hash, AttributeHashStrategy)
```

Now, in the Spec, you can build the Hash like so:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "ClientApi::V1::ClientContexts", type: :request do
  describe "POST /client_api/v1/client_contexts" do
    let(:client_context) { attribute_hash :client_context }
    it "creates a new context" do
      client = create :client
      post "/client_api/v1/client_contexts",
        params: client_context
      expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
    end
  end
end
```

The `attribute_hash` method will be a simple Hash that you can pass as request parameters.